# How to change properties values in weblogic without redeploy?

Tags: java, spring, properties, weblogic, jndi

I want to modify my properties configuration in a web application "a" (written in Spring and deployed in Weblogic) and set those properties from a web application "b".

I've already changed the values of the .properties file without success because weblogic does not update the changes. I have to redeploy my web application "a" to take the updated values.

What is required is to make a web application "b" which allows me to change those properties without a redeploy in weblogic and this changes will be updated in the web application "a"

If there's a way to accomplish this using weblogic / spring objects such as attributes, jndi or any other proposal will be well received, I'm new in the world of weblogic.

**Important:**

The application "a" is deployed in Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 (this cannot be changed) and I don't want to stop and start the web application "a" everytime the properties are changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620958/how-to-dynamically-load-server-configurations-depending-on-server-environment

Comment: your application will load the new properties after a restart

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic does not provide out-of-the-box a way to dynamically reload properties when they are updated. You have to implement your own feature. It can be a listener on the property file for instance.